# tinymce uninitialized constant AppConfig in rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, tinymce

I'm learning Rails as I go, and have been put on a project to update an existing site from Rails 2 to Rails 3.1.1. The app uses tinymce to allow an admin to edit several parts of the site's content. In our upgraded project, when I click this edit link the result is

```
Routing Error
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Admin::ContentController::AppConfig):
app/controllers/admin/content_controller.rb:4:in `<class:ContentController>'
app/controllers/admin/content_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

I have searched all over the internet for help but this is unfortunately a somewhat generic name for a variable I guess? The project is using the gem, tinymce-rails, which I -think- is the correct option for rails 3.1. All I am trying to find out here is what is the root problem, so I know what part of the application needs to be updated so at least the page will load, even if there are more issues I need to fix afterwards...

I verified all of the steps from https://github.com/sandipransing/rails_tiny_mce#readme seem to be implemented (though that says rails 3.0, so I also looked over https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails)... Here's the code in the content controller that throws the error:

```
class Admin::ContentController < ApplicationController
before_filter :require_admin_login

uses_tiny_mce(:options => AppConfig.freysmile_options, :only => [:referral_center, :great_review_tips, :faq, :badge_assignment_mail, :point_assignment_mail, :add_referral_mail, :patient_invitation_mail])
```

The project seems to have tinymce-rails in the gemfile and also the plugins folder - it also has all of the plugins that are listed as being required on the first github link.

(Side note: Unfortunately this is a site made by someone else, given to our consulting boss who is not working with the original creator, and now my fiancee and myself are learning by updating this, so it is built in ways I would probably not have gone, but we do not have time for a complete redo.) Thanks for reading my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `uses_tiny_mce` method is from another gem that is not compatible with rails > 3.1. You want to remove that method from any of your controllers and follow the instructions on the [tinymce-rails](https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails) readme. The tinymce-rails gem simply adds the tinymce javascript to your asset pipeline in rails-3.1+.

I don't know where the AppConfig.freysmile_options comes from. Search your app for 'freysmile'.

Here's how I'm using tinymce-rails with a 3.1.3 app:

Gemfile:

```
gem 'tinymce-rails'
```

application.js

```
//= require tinymce-jquery
```

views/shared/_mce.html.erb

```
<div id="form_content">
  <h3><%= f.label :content %></h3>
  <%= f.text_area :content, :cols => '100', :rows => '50', :class => 'mce' %>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('.mce').tinymce({
      width: 1000,
      theme: 'advanced',
      theme_advanced_toolbar_location: 'top',
      theme_advanced_buttons1: 'bold, italic, underline, strikethrough, justifyleft, justifycenter, justifyright, justifyfull, bullist, numlist, outdent, indent, cut, copy, paste, undo, redo, link, unlink, image, cleanup, code, removeformat, help',
      theme_advanced_buttons2: 'formatselect, fontselect, fontsizeselect, styleselect, hr, sub, sup, forecolor, backcolor, forecolorpicker, backcolorpicker, charmap, visualaid, anchor blockquote',
      theme_advanced_buttons3: ''
    });
  });
</script>
```

forms:

```
<%= render :partial => 'shared/mce', :locals => {:f => f} %>
```

I'm only using tinymce on columns named "content". If your columns have differing names, you'll have to adjust your partial locals to suit.

Maybe there's a better way to customize the buttons and layout without modifying the gem, but this is working well enough for me.

Comment: Thank you so much. Commenting out the line in the controller allows the pages to load and now I realize the tinymce-rails readme doesn't even have anything in the controller. Now I am able to make progress on rendering the editor how it should be. In my searching for upgrading from rails 2 to 3 I didn't see anything about this function changing. I figured it would be something noobish, but hopefully this question can save some other poor soul some time later on. :)